# How do I call the objects created with QtDesigner (or QtCreator) in my code in python? Where is this information in python? PyQt4 please

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, qt-designer, pyqt4

Where can I find a good documentation on how to refer (to call) to the Dialog created with QtDesigner? For example, a buttomBox (or any other) just created. I’m trying to make a plugin, but the tutorials I’ve seen just throw this information in and I just don’t get how to do with the others Widgets. How do I link them in my code? Where is this information? I need to know it for PyQt4. The API I find is not in python. Or is just specified for the use of PyQt4, and I just don’t find, or don’t understand, how to call them to my scripts I already have. PS: I use the Plugin Builder and already have some code of my own, but don’t know how to use them together to work as a plugin.

Comment: Are you sure to you want to keep QT4 and not QT5 ? QGIS 2 is not maintained anymore. Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I am in the process of migrating from python 2 to python 3. I have some standalone scripts written with ArcPy and I'm now also migrating them to PyQGIS and trying to build some plugins for QGIS 2.18.17. If I migrate to QT5, I may have to adequate more things, and I believe, my "headache" may be bigger for now. I want to migrate to QT5 (and others) once my basics on QT4 and the understanding of the whole process of building a plugin be more concrete. Do you think I should do it otherwise? Anyone suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a plugin with Plugin Builder Plugin, let's say a dockwidget, all in all it is self-explaning. You should see in the generated file [plugin_name]_dockwidget.py the comments

```
# Set up the user interface from Designer.
# After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
# self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
# http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
# #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
```

This is from a plugin for QGIS 2, but applies also for PyQGIS 3 and explains well what to do.

For example, when you create a `QPushButton` named `my_push_button` with QtDesigner you access it via e.g.

```
self.my_push_button.clicked.connect(self.the_method)
```

within the dockwidget class, where `the_method(self)` is called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a good start for me to figure it out. Any other tip for knowing what to do with the objects created?  For the 'clicked.connect(self.the_method)' part, for exemplo, what else could I do? Where do I find this? This is relevant because other widgets do other things. Not all of them do simple things as only "push a button".

Comment: # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html is an exemplo of what I wrote in my question: It's not python!

Comment: To learn Python related topics include pyqt4 in your search strings. On https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html for example you learn about the signals a pushbutton is able to emit (section signals). Same for other widgets. The answer above shows how to connect such a signal to a slot (function or method).